# Escalation: Ask team leader if problem is "too big"

Tags: meaning

I am not a native speaker and want to know if "escalation" is the matching word for this:

> I get a question from a customer, and I don't know if I am allowed to answer or do it. I want to go to my team leader to ask him if I am allowed to.

I looked at the wikipedia page for "Escalation" and I can't find a matching definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalation

How to call "Asking the upper hierarchy for help/advice/permission" in the English language?

Answer (score 2):

***[Escalate](http://www.yourdictionary.com/escalate)*** is an appropriate word in current business-speak for this situation.

For example, "I will escalate the issue to my team leader".

[image]

[Here](https://www.pmi.org/en/Escalation-How-to-Do-it-Right.aspx) is a page from the Project Management Institute that has a number of examples of how it is used, but with no definition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If "Escalate" is appropriate I ask myself why no entry of the list (Cost escalation, Conflict escalation, ...) on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escalation matches. At least not my point of view.

Comment: I asked the wikipedia people here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Escalation#Relaxed_Escalation:_Ask_the_leader_is_not_in_the_list

Answer (score 1):

You can simply say that you need to "consult" your senior to check if you can take the task up or not.

Comment: Yes, I could use "consult". But this does not imply "going to a higher hierarchy level".